# Javascript, unexpected token ' ) '

Tags: javascript, dom, unexpected-token

this is my first question here in StackOverflow. I'm learning JS fundamentals. I've tried to re-examine from top to the bottom of the code that I've written and the 'unexpected token ')' ' keeps on reappearing. I rewrote the whole code from a video to make sure I wrote by myself and understand every line of the code as well as making myself familiar to write codes. I've tried to erase the last line code '})' but I wonder why does the error still occur. I hope anyone can help me, this is frustrating !

```
const secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
let score = 20;
document.querySelector('.number').textContent = secretNumber;

document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click',
    function() {
            const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
            console.log(guess, typeof guess);
            if (!guess) {
                document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No Number!';
            } else if (guess === secretNumber) {
                document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Correct Number!';
            } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
                if (score > 1) {
                    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Too High!';
                    score--;
                    document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
                } else {
                    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'You lost the game!';
                    document.querySelector('.score').textContent = 0;
                }
            } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
                if (score > 1) {
                    document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
                        'Too low!';
                    score--;
                    document.querySelector('.score').textContent =
                        score;
                } else {
                    document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
                        'You lost the game!';
                    document.querySelector('.score').textContent = 0;
                };
            });
```

Comment: The error in the console should show you the line number as well.

Comment: How does the HTML for your JS look like?

Comment: Use a code formatter to automatically fix your indentation and the problem becomes much more obvious.

Comment: Use proper indentation, and use variables for elements you use often (e.g. `document.querySelector('.message')`) that require a bunch of work to be done.

Comment: You have a typo error. change all ending brackets with; "};}});"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
const secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
let score = 20;
document.querySelector('.number').textContent = secretNumber;

document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click',
function() {
    const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess')
        .value);
    console.log(guess, typeof guess);
    if (!guess) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
            'No Number!';
    } else if (guess === secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
            'Correct Number!';
    } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
        if (score > 1) {
            document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
                'Too High!';
            score--;
            document.querySelector('.score').textContent =
                score;
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
                'You lost the game!';
            document.querySelector('.score').textContent = 0;
        }
    } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
        if (score > 1) {
            document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
                'Too low!';
            score--;
            document.querySelector('.score').textContent =
                score;
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
                'You lost the game!';
            document.querySelector('.score').textContent = 0;
        };
    }
});
```

You hadn't closed your last if statement `else if (guess > secretNumber)`

Consistent indenting and Sublime text both help solve this problem, see the image below...

[image]

You can see the closing function `})` is one indent deeper than the opening which indicates a unclosed statement. We can also tell by Sublime Texts error highlighting.

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change, why should it solve the problem?

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your input, it's probably down to the way I answer SO questions. I quickly add the "MVP" answer and then expand on it once it's been posted. It's a habit I'm in.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. I am still wondering actually since I was writing the whole same code from a video. Everything was the same but mine does not work and as I have added the ' } ' now it works. Thanks ! Somehow I am still in awe, why does my code doesn't work and the code written by the instructor in the video works ?